# bootstrap 4 nav not full width when collapsed

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have added a bootstrap 4 navbar to my site. When I reduce the veiwport and the navbar collapses, the nav items are not full width, furthermore when you click them they overwite the page below rather than push the page down (although I'm not bothered about this, just curious as to why).
I struggle a bit with navbar coding, but bootstrap 4 has beaten me;

My site is here: http://ccgi.unclezen.plus.com/dev/onwbc/test.php

My navbar code is here:

```
<div class="row navholder justify-content-center">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg justify-content-center">
    <!-- Toggler/collapsible Button using Fontawesome icon -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars burger"></i></span>
    </button>   
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse colour1bg" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item central">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item central">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item central">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item central">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link4</a>
      </li>    
      <li class="nav-item central">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link5</a>
      </li>    
      <li class="nav-item central">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link6</a>
      </li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: The row class is only used to contain columns, not navbar.

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** The `row` class on the wrapper in conjuntion maybe with `positon:absolute` style generates the width issue, just remove it.

**(2)** This: "*when you click them they overwite the page below rather than push the page down*" could be generated also because you have `position: abosolute` set on your navbar, check your CSS styles.

You can check next example, where it works as expected:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="navholder justify-content-center">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light justify-content-center">
  <!-- Toggler/collapsible Button using Fontawesome icon -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>   
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse colour1bg" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item central">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item central">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item central">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item central">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link4</a>
      </li>    
      <li class="nav-item central">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link5</a>
      </li>    
      <li class="nav-item central">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link6</a>
      </li> 
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
</div>

<p>some text...</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just need a few pointers.

I removed the row that I was holding the navbar in
Added the justify-content-center class to the UL element so that the nav was centred
That left the navbar opening how I wanted it when collapsed, full width and pushing the page down
But there was a gap on the ends of the navbar element that didnt line up with the element above that was resolved by adding the custom class below
.navbarCustom
{
 margin-left: -15px;
 margin-right: -15px;
}

Comment: I cant mark this with a green tick as my membership is too new

Comment: Just note that when I pointed to remove the `row` I was reference just the class, not the entire `div`, like shown on my example. Anyway, I'm glad this helps you, you can mark it when you have the permissions, don't worry.